# using navigator.geolocation in UIWebView with local html file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a webapp that uses the html5 navigator.geolocation API. I would like to run it in a UIWebView without using phonegap infrastructure.

When I load the app from local files in ios, the app prompts the user for permission to use the current location (as it should) in the ios simulator, using a file url with the path to the file in the simulator.

On real iPhone hardware, the same app does not throw the permission alert or run the code (presumably because it does not have permission to run). The real hardware can also run the same app over the wire just fine, but in that case the alert uses the remote hostname, not the local name of the app.

It seems like there should be something I can throw in a property file to configure the app to be able to use navigator.geolocation in a local file, or maybe a way to subclass UIWebView to throw the alert myself, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: hi hymenopterans, have you solved this problem?

Comment: Also looking for a solution...  Either customising the content or preventing it (as the containing app has this permission already) would suffice.